# $FolderBrowser.ShowDialog() and automatically select enter

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a small automated snippet. The following snippet displays a folder in a shared drive but I need to automatically use the keystroke <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm the selected folder.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$FolderBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog -Property @{
    SelectedPath = 'S:\FOLDERNAME'
}

$FolderBrowser.ShowDialog()
$FolderBrowser.SelectedPath
```

Once the folder is selected, how do I automate the <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress to confirm the path? I am using PowerShell 5.0.

Comment: "executing after selecting the path" is a typo.Shouldn't be there. My apologies.

Comment: Use the edit feature just below the owershell tag.

Comment: Umm... what is the point of displaying a BrowseFolder dialog when you're auto-selecting a pre-set folder anyway? Just assign the path string to a variable.

Comment: Why do you need to hit keystroke enter?  Is there a reason for this, or would it be simpler to store the folder selection in a variable?  Also, since you set the selected path, could you not just store that in a variable and avoid the folder selection altogether?